# Leftover traces of removed Ubuntu in UEFI and Recovery Devices on Windows

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, uninstall

I recently set up a dual boot of Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1 Enterprise. I booted off a USB stick and had it install alongside Windows rather than over top of it. It installed perfectly, bootloader was great, etc. I decided I didn't like the version of Linux I had chosen, so without looking up a tutorial I went to remove Linux. On the windows side I deleted the Linux partitions, but didn't do anything about restoring the windows boot loader.

Unsurprisingly (in hindsight), I couldn't boot into Windows, and got grub command line every time I attempted. Using a Windows recovery disk I attempted to fix it with the recovery console commands `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixboot` neither of which worked. I got to a bootable Windows by reinstalling the OS overtop of everything. Never saw grub command line again. However, [there are still traces of Ubuntu in certain places](https://imgur.com/DWPxCl7&Np6J3UR&B9APWRG&g6bNeuG).
In UEFI, the Hard Disk is specified as using Windows Boot Manager which I found peculiar. So I opened the Hard Disk BBS Priorities and sure enough there are two ubuntu options. I also noticed that if I go to Advanced Startup in Windows, choose Use a Device, ubuntu appears twice as an option.

So far the steps I've taken to try and fix this are:

- Using recovery console, `rebuildbcd` which failed
- Using command prompt, `bcdedit` which returned no entry about ubuntu
- Mounting the EFS partition of C: and deleting the ubuntu directory (failed)
- Going into msconfig to delete Ubuntu. [Ubuntu wasn't present.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al3fg.jpg)

After a few days of googling I am completely out of ideas for what I can search for to find tutorials for this specific problem, because I'm not familiar with the places I'm finding ubuntu traces. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can do to remove the last of Ubuntu on this machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: Also [How do I remove “Ubuntu” in the bios boot menu? (UEFI)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi#63613) and [Removing entries from UEFI menu with efibootmgr](http://askubuntu.com/questions/348763/removing-entries-from-uefi-menu-with-efibootmgr/348776)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're seeing are NVRAM entries. You can delete them in Windows using [EasyUEFI,](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) or using an Ubuntu live CD with the `efibootmgr` command-line program. (You'll type `sudo efibootmgr` to see the entries, then delete them with `sudo efibootmgr -b {####} -B`, where `{####}` is the four-digit hexadecimal number for an entry found with the first `efibootmgr` command.)

That said, these entries are basically harmless, so long as they aren't set as the default. You can safely ignore them.

For future reference, re-installing Windows was drastic overkill. Most computers provide an EFI boot manager that you can access by hitting Esc, Enter, or a function key (usually something in the F8-F12 range). Using that, you could have booted Windows, then used `bcdedit` or EasyUEFI to reset the Windows boot loader as the default.

Comment: Thanks so much, your solution worked perfectly. I'm glad to know they were harmless entries. I'll keep your advice in mind if I ever cause this problem to happen again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the UEFI partition in Windows.

Do that from an administrative command prompt.

```
diskpart
list partition
select partition x:
assign letter=b (or whatever available disk letter you want)
exit (that only exits diskpart)
```

in same admin prompt:

```
taskkill /im explorer.exe /f
explorer.exe (launches explorer with admin rights)
```

after that, I recommend unmounting the UEFI partition when you are done.